# Date-Timestamp parameter in pentaho reporting

Tags: reporting, pentaho, reportparameter

how to add/display timestamp while creating a report using pentaho report designer 3.6, having date as a parameter and when the user chose the date, the  timestamp should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

Define your parameter as type "Timestamp" or "Date" (not Date (SQL)!). All you need to do then is to display your parameter in a date-field with the correct format-string to display time-elements.